# flagging difference between

Tags: discussion, flags, migration

I've noticed a lot of questions on stackoverflow that are things like whats the difference between framework A and framework B  or language A & B

it is my option that theses question are off topic for stackoverflow and should go onto [programmers.stackexchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) yet there are allot of people supporting these kinds of questions with up votes and answers should I be flagging to move them or are they ok?

Comment: Mostly pointless, shouldn't be migrated.

Comment: @jzd could you elaborate on that I don't see how it's pointless

Comment: I didn't say it was pointless, that was @Will.   However, I somewhat agree with him as some questions might fit better on SO, so I might a call on one question but not the other.  Either way they are not hugely off topic, does moving them really provide any advantage.

Comment: @jzd sorry, my mistaken copy paste, not that i can think of but the question is not based code based and neither is the answer so reputations would be skewed

Comment: I'd be tempted to say framework choice is probably on topic, but language choice isn't. But don't quote me